# Pass a callback function to polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to pass a function/method reference using template binding.
Should this work? What am I doing wrong?

**index.dart**

```dart
@observable
class Model() {
  onSignOutCallback(message) {
    print(message);
  }
}

main() {
  query("#tmpl").xtag.model = new Model(); 
  TemplateElement t = query("#plus-login-tmpl") as TemplateElement;
  t.bindingDelegate = new PolymerExpressions();
}
```

**index.html**

...
    
      
      
    
    ...

**my_component.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="my-component" attributes="sign-out-callback">
  <button on-click="{{signOutCallback}}>Sign out</span>
</polymer-element>
```

**my_component.dart**

```dart
typedef void OnSignOutCallback(message);

@CustomTag("my-component")
class MyComponent extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  OnSignOutCallback onSignOutCallback;

  @override
  inserted() {
    super.inserted();
    onSignOutCallback("signed out"); // test if value was assigned        
  }
}
```

Comment: What error(s) do you see?

Comment: I don't get an error but nothing get's assigned. I edited the question. As it seems the template must have a PolymerExpression assigned and more strange only methods with exactly one parameter without a type annotation are supported.The code as now written in my question works. Is it intentional that only this form is supported or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the model as following

```dart
class Model() {
  var onSignOutCallback;

  Model(){
    onsignOutCallback = signOutCallback;
  }

  signOutCallback(message) {
    print(message);
  }
}
```

It seems that it currently is not possible to reference methods directly in HTML as it does inside a Polymer element.
Assigning the method to a field in the model and referencing the field in HTML works though.